# Not able to host a Unity Netcode Game on specific device, but I'm able to join as a client on the same device

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unity-networking

I'm trying to create a Unity netcode LAN connection between a few devices. It works fine with a few devices as the host or the client, but some devices can only connect as a client and are not able to host the game. Even though working under a corporate security firewall, I always enable inbound and outbound ports for all the devices under firewall settings. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening only for certain devices?

Also, the devices which works fine has my Windows account. The one that is not able to host the game has a different Windows account, but they are able to join as a client. Could the Windows accounts be an issue?

Comment: This sounds like a NAT issue to me.

Comment: Hey @Philipp, can you elaborate your answer please. It would be a great help.

Comment: I am afraid I can't really give you a constructive answer because I don't have much experience with Unity Netcode. Also I am more of a programmer than a network administrator. But when some devices can act as a client but not as a server, then that is usually a problem with network address translation (NAT) and port forwarding being misconfigured.